# Is there way in ggplot to show multiple points at very same coordinates as a larger bubble, with size depending on the number of points at one spot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If have found solutions using the plotrix package ->sizeplot, but this is an issue I encounter quite frequently and I would like to use ggplot if possible. Very glad for a help in advance or the information that ggplot is not a perfect enviroment for this.

Comment: If I understood correctly, yes it would be possible using the count for each coordinate as the size, a `add_count(x,y)` before the ggplot2 could work. But it would be better if you can provide a sample of your data with `dput()`

Comment: An alternative to bubble plot you might consider is the `geom_hex` heatmap.

Comment: It's not exactly what you are asking for, but you may find `geom_jitter()` useful - it's similar to `geom_point()` but adds a random amount of `x` and `y` noise to each point. This means multiple points at exactly the same coords will be visibly denser than other areas. Using `shape = 1` (open circle) is good for showing areas of high density too, as it's obvious when points overlap as the area becomes denser in colour.

Comment: To formalize the comment of @ViníciusFélix, if your dataframe is `df`, use `dplyr` and `ggplot2` and this should work:  `df %>% add_count(x,y) %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(size=n))`.  The function `add_count(...)` will compare `x,y` and give you the tally of each matching pair in a new column called `n`.